# MVC4 less conversion

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, less

I am trying to understand how to utilize .less conversion with MVC4.

I want to programmaticaly replace .less variables with values of my own at runtime.

Given the following code, how would I pass my variable values (to be replaced) into the parser?

```
public class CustomTransform : IBundleTransform
{
    private readonly CssMinify _cssMinify = new CssMinify();

    public void Process(BundleContext context, BundleResponse response)
    { 
        response.Content = dotless.Core.Less.Parse(response.Content);
        _cssMinify.Process(context, response);
    }
}
```

Edit: An example solution would be amazing.

Answer (score 0):

I would totally just jam them into the content at the start, ie

```
public void Process(BundleContext context, BundleResponse response)
{ 
    string myContent = "";
    foreach(var variable in myCustomVariables)
         myContent += String.Format("@{0}={1};", variable.Name, variable.Value);

    response.Content = dotless.Core.Less.Parse(myContent + response.Content);
    _cssMinify.Process(context, response);
}
```

Havent compiled the above (and you could write it nicer with stringbuilder) but it should show the basic idea

Comment: sounds great, the only question is on a per request basis how would you inject the customvariables into the transform? is that even possible?

Comment: @shenku per-request is a completely different kettle of fish, to do this you would need to dynamically generate your less file on the fly.  this would mean removing it from bundling altogether, creating an action which serves your css file (with the correct content type) and doing the replacement then.

Comment: yea, that is what i currently do, thought there might be a neater way. thanks for the input.